# Drupal rule issue with db_query

Tags: mysql, drupal-7

I have called a function "logCommentNotification" from drupal rule "on comment on any node" and I have written this function on a custom module.

It is giving an error when I am committing on any node(I am using ajax comment module).

Below is the function.

```
function logCommentNotification( $cid ){


$strSql = "SELECT 
                c.nid, c.uid AS commented_by, n.uid AS author_id
            FROM 
                comment c
                JOIN node n ON( c.nid = n.nid )
            WHERE c.cid = " . $cid;

$dbQueryObj = db_query( $strSql );
}
```

Please find error of screenshot.

Please help me this.

[image]

Comment: Please check ajax response in browser console. I think ajax not getting your function.